# Inputbox to select slides in Powrpoint presentation. (Almost done)

Tags: arrays, vba, select, powerpoint, inputbox

Hello all smart peeps out there,

I want to select some Powerpointslides based on inputs from the inputbox and I can't get it to work. It's probably something wrong with the how I declare variables. I have created a macro which names Powerpointslides and I want to select the name of the slides with the inputbox with the help of VBA.

So basically I want the inputbox to return an Array of slide names. Let's say: I want to select a sheet called USA and Sweden if I enter it in the input box. This is what I have tried so far.

```
Sub Select_Slides()


slides = InputBox("Insert Slide names to select")

list = Array(slides)

ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(list).Select

End Sub
```

In order for it to work list has do be be an Array of a sheet called USA and Sweden. I have a macro which creates a new Powerpoint with only selected slides. So this is why I want to select slides via the input box.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a reminder:  The Split method can do most of the heavy lifting when you need to convert a delimited string to an array.

```
Sub SplitExample()

    Dim sText As String
    ' This would be your InputBox results, but for demo purposes:
    Dim aInputarray() As String
    Dim x As Long

    sText = "USA,Sweden"

    ' Split takes the text to split and the delimiter as parameters
    ' and returns a 0-based array
    aInputarray = Split(sText, ",")

    For x = LBound(aInputarray) To UBound(aInputarray)
        Debug.Print aInputarray(x)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I did know about the split function Before, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to format the string the `InputBox` will return. I wrote this function called `CreateCorrectArray` that will take the names of slides from your `slides` string whereas a comma separator. Example, if you want to select the slides named "Slide1" and "Slide4", you need to input "Slide1,Slide4" in the InputBox, so the function will return an Array("Slide1", "Slide4").

```
Sub Select_Slides()

    slides = InputBox("Insert Slide names to select")

    list = CreateCorrectArray(slides)

    ActivePresentation.slides.Range(list).Select

End Sub

'' Create the array from string whereas comma separator
Function CreateCorrectArray(ByVal slides As String) As String()
    Dim indexChar As Integer
    Dim indexAr As Integer
    Dim startOfSlideName As Integer
    Dim MyArray() As String
    Dim nSlides As Integer

    '' Number of slides
    nSlides = ActivePresentation.slides.Count

    '' Array that storage the slides names
    ReDim MyArray(nSlides)


    indexAr = 1
    startOfSlideName = 1 '' start of slide name in the string "slides"

    '' Loop trough each character in "slide" string
    For indexChar = 1 To Len(slides)

        '' if the character is a comma
        If Mid(slides, indexChar, 1) = "," Then

           '' storage the slide's name in the array
           MyArray(indexAr) = Mid(slides, startOfSlideName, indexChar - startOfSlideName)

           indexAr = indexAr + 1
           startOfSlideName = indexChar + 1
        End If

        '' At the end of slides string, there will be
        '' no comma, so for this case, add the last
        '' slide name in MyArray
        If indexChar = Len(slides) Then
            MyArray(indexAr) = Mid(slides, startOfSlideName)
        End If
    Next

    CreateCorrectArray = MyArray
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The following macro will prompt the user to list one or more slide names to be selected separated by a semi-colon, and it includes some error handling as well.

```
Sub Select_Slides()

    Dim slideNames As String
    Dim slideNameArray As Variant
    Dim selectedSlideRange As slideRange
    Dim i As Long

    'prompt user to list slide names using a semi-colon as a separator
    slideNames = InputBox("Insert slide names to select using a semi-colon as a separator.")

    'if inputbox is empty, or user cancelled, exit sub
    If Len(slideNames) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Inputbox is either empty, or user cancelled!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'split the names into an array
    slideNameArray = Split(slideNames, ";")

    'remove any leading or trailing spaces
    For i = LBound(slideNameArray) To UBound(slideNameArray)
        slideNameArray(i) = Trim(slideNameArray(i))
    Next i

    'assign the selected slides to a slide range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set selectedSlideRange = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(slideNameArray)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If selectedSlideRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "One or more listed slides not found!", vbExclamation
    Else
        selectedSlideRange.Select
    End If

    Set selectedSlideRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, highly appriciated! It works fine and I would not have been able to figure it out on my own.